# Probability that two different size lists, drawn from the same pool, will have common members

Tags: probability, hypergeometric-distribution

Two companies are marketing their similar products to a limited pool of 400,000 eligible customers.  Company A has 2500 customers total.  Company B has 150 customers total.  Upon examination of the two customer lists, it is determined that Company B has 50 customers that are also on Company A's customer list.  Company A believes that Company B may be targeting its customer list.  What is the probability that Company B would have so many common customers?  How can this be expressed numerically, i.e., the probability that the two lists would have 50 common customers if customers were targeted by each company randomly from the pool, is 1 in a trillion.

Comment: Modeling all 400,000 eligible customers as equally likely to be on any company's list seems unrealistic: companies target the best prospects.  For instance, maybe both companies are marketing to a commercial list of a few thousand eligible customers. Thus, any answer you get will be (a) astronomically small (it's $4.15 \times 10^{-71}$) and (b) unrealistic.  That will make it difficult, if not impossible, to draw any meaningful conclusions from this probability exercise.

Comment: I agree with whuber's assessment of the unrealistic nature of the question (and the consequent impact on how meaningful the conclusions would be) but your tag choice essentially answers the question you asked taking the premises of the question as given. Take 400000 balls representing each eligible customer; make the 2500 balls representing Company A's customers white and the rest black, place in a large container, mix well and draw 150 for Company B's customers. However, since 150 is very small compared to 400000 you could also approximate ... ctd

Comment: ctd...  it [with a binomial and in turn a Poisson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftuir.png) though you would not have good relative accuracy quite so far into the tail as you are. Compare the example at the Wikipedia page on the [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Application_and_example) and substitute white for green (etc). Note that you don't seek the probability of exactly 50, but at least 50 (not that it makes much difference). As whuber notes, the probability is astronomically small but meaningless because the assumptions are not remotely tenable.

Comment: Whuber and Glen- thank you both for your thoughts - Assume that the 400,000 eligible customers is already a subset of 3.5 million total customers, so each of the 400,000 is already deemed a "best prospect".  The facts here are modified, but taken from a legal dispute, and the exercise is intended to show how extremely unlikely it is that Company B would have so many common customers if it wasn't targeting a list potentially stolen from Company A.  We want to express the fact that that many common customers is mathematically unlikely to have occurred without some external influence.